# Is there always $B\subseteq A$ with $f(B)=B$?

Tags: combinatorics

Let $f:A\rightarrow A$ be a function between finite sets. Is there always a non-empty subset $B\subseteq A$ with $f(B)=B$ ?

I think there is, but I am not sure how to prove it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The sequence $A,f(A),f(f(A)),\ldots$ is decreasing, but it cannot decrease strictly for more than $|A|$ steps, so for some $n$, $f^n(A)=f^{n+1}(A)=f(f^n(A))$.

Comment: Very nice ${}{}{}{}$ thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want $B\neq A$, then no: Let $A=\{1,2\}$ and $f(1)=2$, $f(2)=1$. More generally, a cyclic permutation of $A$ will work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure $B\subseteq A$ means B can be equal to A.

Comment: yeah, any cyclic permutation works. But I am allowing $B=A$.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to fall to strong induction. Suppose it is true for subsets of size $n$ or smaller.

Take $A$ of size $n$. If the function is bijective we are done (take $B=A$). Otherwise pick $x$ that is not in the image of $f$. Notice that the image of $f$ restricted to $A\setminus\{x\}$ is a subset of $A\setminus \{x\}$. So we apply the inductive hypothesis with the function $f$ restricted to $A\setminus \{x\}$ and find an appropriate "fixed" subset.